# Multiple words sequence labeling

Tags: nlp

Suppose there are title "Reflections of a Recovering Aggregationist" and I want to tag or label it as a single tag says "Title".

So the question is, can we tag multiple words as a single tag or not?

I know tagging will be word by word and  I know the process.

```
Reflections of a Recovering Aggregationist  - Title
The Role of the Judge in Non-Class Settlements - Title
U. PA. L. RE V.                                - Title
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are looking to tag phrases. Phrases are usually tagged using [IOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)) Tags. For e.g. "Alex is going to Los Angeles", here "Alex" is a name and "Los Angeles" is a city or phrase (geopolitical entity). It will be tagged as:

```
Alex B-PER
is O
going O
to O
Los B-LOC
Angeles I-LOC
```

Similarly for your case, tagging will be as follows.

```
Reflections B-TITLE
of I-TITLE
a I-TITLE
Recovering I-TITLE
Aggregationist I-TITLE
```

Usually NER problems are solved using such tagging.